# Cyclic Shift (Rotate Rows) Dataframe with Groupy Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

im trying to apply np.roll with groupy of pandas.

Actually, i have this dataframe:
(In the columns complete_contracts_shift i applied shift with groupby:

```
df.groupby(['contracts ','param_contrct'])['complete_contracts '].shift(1)
```

| complete_contracts | contracts | param_contrct | complete_contracts_shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F21-EZ-01/01/2022 | F21 | EZ | NaN |
| F21-EZ-02/01/2022 | F21 | EZ | F21-EZ-01/01/2022 |
| F21-EZ-03/01/2022 | F21 | EZ | F21-EZ-02/01/2022 |
| F21-AB-01/01/2022 | F21 | AB | NaN |
| F21-AB-02/01/2022 | F21 | AB | F21-AB-01/01/2022 |
| F21-AB-03/01/2022 | F21 | AB | F21-AB-02/01/2022 |

I need that dataframe has the column 'complete_contracts_shift' as follows:

| complete_contracts | contracts | param_contrct | complete_contracts_shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F21-EZ-01/01/2022 | F21 | EZ | F21-EZ-03/01/2022 |
| F21-EZ-02/01/2022 | F21 | EZ | F21-EZ-01/01/2022 |
| F21-EZ-03/01/2022 | F21 | EZ | F21-EZ-02/01/2022 |
| F21-AB-01/01/2022 | F21 | AB | F21-AB-03/01/2022 |
| F21-AB-02/01/2022 | F21 | AB | F21-AB-01/01/2022 |
| F21-AB-03/01/2022 | F21 | AB | F21-AB-02/01/2022 |

i know np.roll of numpy, but i cant combinate this with groupby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it with this code!

````py
_df['complete_contracts_shift'] = _df.groupby(['contracts','param_contrct'])['complete_contracts'].transform(lambda x: np.roll(x.values,1))```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this result and consistently missing the third month. I suggest to go for a more simplistic approach with:

```
df['complete_contracts_shift'] = np.where(df['complete_contracts_shift'].isna(),df['contracts']+'-'+df['param_contrct']+'-03/01/2022',df['complete_contracts_shift']
```

This will help you fill the `NaN` values with the correct combination of columns and date values.

The data you provide is pitifully not enough for me to give more a detailed answer.

Comment: This exaple that i shown is more simple, really i have more days and month, in this case, the third day is the last